# How to combine two SELECT queries with their own order

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two SELECT queries. They are sorted on their own. I want to combine them into one while not changing their order.

For example, the first SELECT query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "Smith%" ORDER BY name
```

This returns

```
name
--------
SmithABC
SmithBCD
SmithDEF
```

And I have another SELECT query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%Smith%" AND name NOT LIKE "Smith%" ORDER BY name
```

This one returns

```
name
--------
ABCSmithEF
DEFSmithGH
XYZSmithXY
```

**Desired result:**

```
name
--------
SmithABC
SmithBCD
SmithDEF
ABCSmithEF
DEFSmithGH
XYZSmithXY
```

*in that order*.

If this is possible in one SELECT query with some complex ORDER BY, that's fine. What I want is, just make them into *one* result with ordering like above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### General solution: Use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT table.*, 1 subquery FROM table 
WHERE name LIKE 'Smith%'
UNION ALL
SELECT table.*, 2 subquery FROM table 
WHERE name LIKE '%Smith%' AND name NOT LIKE 'Smith%'
ORDER BY subquery, name
```

In order to retain the order of the select statements, you can introduce an artificial column by which you will order first, before ordering by `name`

#### Specific solution: Use a more sophisticated `ORDER BY` expression:

In your example, the two subqueries are actually mutually exclusive, due to your predicates. So you could also write

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE name LIKE '%Smith%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name LIKE 'Smith%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, name
```

#### Note:

While [SQLite accepts double quotes `"`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) as string delimiters, I strongly suggest using single quotes `'` instead, as most databases (including SQLite) use double quotes to delimit case-sensitive identifiers.